# Getx check if named route exists before routing

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-routes

I am using Getx routing with deeplinks. I want to add a protection where I check if the deeplink route that comes in is valid or not. Is there a function I have not found that does this?

The code would be as simple as:

```
var str = 'my/deep/link'
if(doesNamedRouteExist(str)){
   Get.toNamed(str);
}
```

Any ideas/recommendations/elegant solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use the GetX but you could do something like: `bool exists = false; Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) { if (route.settings.name == str) exists = true; return false;});`

Comment: I would recommend using `static const id = "route name"` as property in screens/class. Then using that const variable in `Get.toNamed(MyApp.id)`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Check if route exists in route tree using the function below

```dart
bool matchRoute(String routeName) {
    for (var route in Get.routeTree.routes) {
      if (route.name == Homepage.name) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

This function gets a list of routes in the route tree using `Get.routeTree.routes` and then checks through the list of routes to find the route with the same name as `routeName`

This solution works for named routes

Answer (score 0):

Get has the following method:

```
Get.routeTree.matchRoute(path)
```

We used it in this fashion:

```
static bool isPathValid(String path) {
    // If exactly matches root then it is fine.
    if (path.removeAllWhitespace == '/') return true;

    final List<GetPage<dynamic>> treeBranch =
        Get.routeTree.matchRoute(path).treeBranch;

    // Note: for some reason .where was not working on the .treeBranch iterable.
    final List<String> list = <String>[];
    for (final GetPage<dynamic> element in treeBranch) {
      // Need to exclude '/' as it is the root route so any uri beginning
      // with / will give a valid path
      if (element.name != '/') {
        list.add(element.name);
      }
    }

    return list.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

As you can see by the commenting the match route will go through all valid routes and if your root route is '/' any path that has '/' can give a false positive of a valid route. You see we exclude that here. I would recommend experimenting a bit with it.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using

```dart
static const id = "route name"
```

as property in screens/class.

Then using that const variable in

```dart
Get.toNamed(MyAppScreenA.id)
```

- Another way would be to create a constants file for route names and store that id variable there.

Comment: The thing is there are routes that have variable ids in the route string ie /thing/route/1/page could also be /thing/route/2/page where the number could vary and is not static. I would think Getx would have an easy way to match existing route uri names. This also doesn't answer the question: I am looking for a way to match deeplink routes with route names.